# When to use "Follow Redirects" & "Redirect Automatically" while recording with jmeter.

Tags: redirect, jmeter, recording

I want to know the difference between **Follow Redirects** and **Redirect Automatically** while recording with Jmeter.
Also what effect will both these have when used with **Retrieve all Embedded Resources from HTML**

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`Redirect automatically`, will not consider redirect as a separate request
where as `Follow redirects` will consider each redirection as a separate request.

This difference can be visualized in the Listener (View Results Tree).

If `Retrieve all Embedded Resources from HTML` is checked, it will give you `Page Load Time`, since apart from response time it will keep on calculating the time taken till all the supporting files of html page have been downloaded to Local (CSS, Images, Javascript files.. etc.)

Also if any values needs to be captured from redirect request you need to set configuration a follow redirect otherwise will not be able to capture those data using extractors (set cookie values for example)

Hope this will help.