# Sample time (ms) is different from the response time of Loadrunner for the same request. Why is it so?

Tags: jmeter, loadrunner

We recorded a request for launching a website page in **Jmeter** excluding all the static content files css, js etc. When we replayed the script, **the Sample time( considering that it is the response time) was coming around 5000ms.**

We recorded the same request in **LoadRunner** and **the response time was coming around 300ms**. Also when we saw the response time for the request through **HTTPFox** it was also around **300ms**.

My question is why there is a drastic difference between the response time measured by the two tools. Am i going wrong while calculating the response time in jmeter OR is there any other way to calculate response time in Jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

I can see several reasons on why this can happen:

1. JMeter is configured to ["Redirect automatically" or to "Follow Redirects"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602747/when-to-use-follow-redirects-redirect-automatically-while-recording-with-j)
2. JMeter is configured to "Download embedded resources"
3. Your system under test demonstrates high Latency (amount of time for the request to reach the server, JMeter reports overall response time as latency + actual response time, see [The Load Reports](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65153-the-load-reports) guide for metrics explanation)

Comment: Jmeter is configured to "Follow Redirects" and the checkbox for "Download embedded resources" is unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of architectural differences which can contribute to this difference between the tools.  Narrow your scope to one request, such as an image, and scale up your number of users in both tools to see what happens.

You also have test configuration items that can come into play, such as JMETER running monolithic on one host vs loadrunner running distributed amonst many generators.  Think time setting differences, number of users. etc...   You could spend all day nailing the jello of test settings and architecture.

But, given that the Loadrunner time is closest to observable with a proxy and manual execution what can you infer about the rest of your test data?

Comment: While running the test in jmeter there were 3 Load Generators and same goes for LoadRunner. Even we checked with recording just one launch page transaction with both the tools still the difference was the same. But yes the way the tools calculate the response time is different thats why may be we are getting different response time values.